# Cannot Update Two Mongodb Collections in one Mutation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a project using node.js with graphql and mongodb as my database in the backend. In this project, I have a `Project` collection and an `EditedProject` collection, which contains the edits to a project that a user made. Additionally, I have an editProject mutation, which changes the `Project` information to the approved `EditedProject` information based off of the `originalProjectId`. In this mutation, I need the document in the `Project` collection to be updated and the document in the `EditedProject` collection containing these edits to be deleted. The problem that I'm having is that only the `Project` collection is being updated. However, if I comment out

```
const project = await Project.updateOne({"_id":new ObjectId(originalProjectId)}, 
            {$set: { 
            "date": input.date,
            "type": input.type, 
            "edited":'Approved', 
           }})
const editResult = await project.save();
```

```
const deleteEditedProject = await EditedProject.find({"originalProjectId":originalProjectId})
const deleteResult = await deleteEditedProject.save();
```

goes through. Following `const project = await Project.updateOne({ ... const editResult = await project.save();`,  `console.log(originalProjectId)` does not return anything in the terminal. Is this due to `.save()`? Is there a way to work around this? I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work, and I would really appreciate any help or advice. Thank you!

```
import EditedProject from '../../models/EditedProject.js';
import Project from '../../models/Project.js';
import { requireAuth } from '../../services/auth.js';
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";


export default { 
editeProject: async (_, {input}) => {
        try {
            const originalProjectId = input.originalProjectId
            const project = await Project.updateOne({"_id":new ObjectId(originalProjectId)}, 
            {$set: { 
            "date": input.date,
            "type": input.type, 
            "edited":'Approved', 
           }})
           const editResult = await project.save();
           console.log(originalProjectId)
           const deleteEditedProject = await EditedProject.find({"originalProjectId":originalProjectId})
           const deleteResult = await deleteEditedProject.save();        
           return originalProjectId;
            } 
         catch (error) {
            return {
            errorMessage:error.message
            };
            }
        },
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `updateOne` and then `save`?

Comment: Have you looked at mongodb transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use save after updateOne
if you want updated record than use findOneAndUpdate()
for Example:

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update,{new:1})
```

above query will give you updated record

And If you want to perform update on two collection then you can use the
transaction.

In mongoose you can achieve it by using transaction
refer the official documentation
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html